# rails 3, 2 check_boxes shouldn't be false at the same time, how?

Tags: ruby, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a form like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>

      <%= render '/shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      ........

      <% if current_user.admin? %>

      <%= f.label :admin %>
      <%= f.check_box :admin, {checked: true} %>

      <br /><br />

      <%= f.label :developer %>
      <%= f.check_box :developer %>

      <% end %>

     ........

      <%= f.submit "Invite new user", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see, there are two `check_box`s to determine whether the new user admin or developer. Admin is checked by default.

**What I want to do is,** when somebody click checked admin, it won't be unchecked. When click developer, admin will be unchecked and developer will be checked.

New user must be either admin or developer. Both check_boxes should never false at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality (only one possible choice) is for radio button, not checkbox

Comment: I know, but both admin and developer are separate attributes. Are radio buttons for separate choices for 1 attribute? If I can use radio buttons in my case, then how?

Comment: @kalahari if a user can't be both an admin and a dev, why having two separate attributes? Why not having a `role` text field in your db (with inclusion validation in `['admin', 'developer']`)? That said, having checkboxes that behave like radio button may be confusing from a user point of view.

Comment: I did this because I am new. I will try it, lets see

Comment: is this a true questioning `current_user.role("admin")?`  ?

Comment: No, `current_user.role == 'admin'`. But if you go this way, you will probably to define an `admin?` method

Answer (score 1):

use radio buttons. If you still insist on using checkboxes, give both the check boxes a class name, bind the class in a javascript with live and do the validation !

```
$('.checkboxes').live('change', function(){

    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        dosomething...
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know how to bind the class in javascript with live

Comment: something like this


    $('.checkboxes').live('change', function(){

        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            dosomething...
        }
    });

Comment: added an example with the answer

Comment: ok, where should I put this? `assets/javascripts/application.js` or `assets/javascripts/users.js.coffee` or somewhere else?

Comment: you can put it in any js file. The only thing is it should be loaded with your view ! Application js is loaded by default unless configured extensively. So application js should do. To verify use fire bug and check the java scripts loaded when the page is loaded.

Comment: I gave a class name `'yetki'` to both checkboxes. In this function, where should I use it so it can be recognized?

Comment: instead of .checkboxes use .yetki ... Please go through basics of binding javascripts. Just google it and you will understand it.